# Passing props to temperate literal in map

Tags: javascript, templates, reactjs, ecmascript-6, literals

I'm trying to create a dynamic select box. I'm passing the row source data, and the name of key display name. I can't combine the data object with the string key or display name. Thanks!

```
const { rowSourceData, rowSourceKey, rowSourceDisplay } = this.props;
const rowSource = rowSourceData
    .map(data => {          
      return (
        <option key={data.`${rowSourceKey}`}> {data.`${rowSourceDisplay}`}</option>            
      )       
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
const { rowSourceData, rowSourceKey, rowSourceDisplay } = this.props;
const rowSource = rowSourceData
    .map((data,i) => {          
        return (
            <option key={i/*data[rowSourceKey]*/}> {data[rowSourceDisplay]}</option>            
        )       
    })
```

For Example:

```js
obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4};
temp = 'c';
console.log(obj[temp]); // print 3;
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I not get "Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop."? I don't get it when I hard code the key name.

Comment: means ur key values are not unique, to handle this case of unique key, u can use the index of item, use any variable as the index of item, then pass that as the key. it will not throw any error :)

Comment: appreciate your help! I spent about 3 hours on this :)

Comment: glad, to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolve it like

```
const rowSource = rowSourceData
    .map(data => {          
      return (
        <option key={data[rowSourceKey]}> {data[rowSourceDisplay]}</option>            
      )       
  })
```

However since you are using the same key you will get the duplicate key warning. Your key should be unique. You can have the index be the key of the option like

```
const rowSource = rowSourceData
    .map((data, index) => {          
      return (
        <option key={index}> {data[rowSourceDisplay]}</option>            
      )       
  })
```

Comment: This would result in something like `<option key=data.someKey>`... not the actual value in `data.someKey`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I saw the other answer first.

Comment: No problem. i may have been a little late in answering